# Verificar índice atual e próximo índice igual a zero python

Tags: python, loop

Preciso percorrer uma lista em Python como por exemplo:

```
l = [2313, 1221, 1333, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Gostaria que se o elemento atual e o próximo da lista forem iguais a zero
    substitui o elemento atual e o próximo por 1.

Ou se o elemento atual e o anterior forem iguais a zero:
    substitui o elemento atual e o anterior por 1.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Ola @Allan, reparei na sua nova pergunta. Mas copiou mal, cuidado com if que é for ciclo for, veja em baixo como fiz

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado mesmo Miguel! Não tinha reparado nisso, sou iniciante em Python e preciso resolver um problema de alocação de exames, então é meio tenso haha prestarei mais atenção :D

Comment: Sem problema é isso que quer certo?

Comment: Sim sim, ótimo! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
l = [0, 0, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0]
lCount = len(l)
next1 = False

for i in range(0, lCount-1):
    if(l[i] == 0 and l[i+1] == 0):
        l[i] = 1
        next1 = True
    elif(next1):
        l[i] = 1
        next1 = False

if(next1): # ultimo elemento caso seja 0 seguido de outro (next1 definido no ultimo loop do ciclo)
    l[-1] = 1

print(l) # [1, 1, 2313, 1221, 0, 1333, 66, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```